# DataTable keep state after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table which reloads its data at a period of time and it should keep the state after each reload. I've tried using `"stateSave": true` but without success.

Is there a way to keep the state (search, paging) after each data reload? Is `clear` the one that makes the table loose its state?

Here is my code - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dana15/nwhtk7q1/14/)

I don't have much experience with DataTables so, please, be gentle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State is being saved, but some of it is being overwritten by the code in your reload loop.

*State which is being saved and preserved:*

- Sorting (clicking on column headings)
- Filtering (using the gloabl filter input control).
- Records per page ("show x entries")

Steps: (1) I open my copy of your web page, and change these items. (2) I close the web page. (3) I re-open the page. The above items are preserved.

*State which is being overwritten by your code:*

- Paging (moving from page 1 to page 2)

If I do this, then when I close and return to the page, my pagination selection is no longer on page 2.

But the pagination selection *was* actually saved.

It's just that your code immediately overwrites the saved value, when the page is re-opened, before the first table draw:

```
else table.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
```

So, you never get to see the previously saved pagination applied by the user.

When the table is cleared and the data is reloaded, that is basically applying a new pagination, overwriting your saved one.

---

State saving works by saving data to your browser's local storage. It is there where the page change (page 1 to page 2) is stored.

You can see this for yourself by opening your browser tools (F12), and locating the Local Storage entry for your table.

When you move to page 2, you see this:

[image]

This means: *start with the 10th record and show 10 records per page*

(note that the 10th record is actually the 11th since the index is zero-based).

If you watch this `start` value in your browser, you will see it being reset back to zero when your refresh code runs.